# При присвоении сложенных строк с пробелом, результат выводится в 9-ти переменных вместо 3-х. Python

Tags: python, list, append

Допустим сам код на Python:

```
x = "tyr"
y = 'red'
result = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    result.append((''.join(x[1] + (' - ') + y[1])).split())
print(result)

[['y', '-', 'e'], ['y', '-', 'e'], ['y', '-', 'e']]
```

Но если убрать пробеk:

```
 result.append((''.join(x[1] + ('-') + y[1])).split())

[['y-e'], ['y-e'], ['y-e']]
```

Почему так происходит и как получить результат [['y - e'], ['y - e'], ['y - e']], но не через replace.

Comment: Изучи что метод .split() делает. Должно помочь.

Comment: Я знаю что делает метод сплит, я уже разобрался.Я добавлял его потому что до этого в задаче при присвоении результат разделялся, но почему то при добавлении split() наоборот все выводилось вместе, хотя этот метод должен разделять.Но для этого примера он не нужен.

Comment: А есть понимание как именно split разделяет? Он же должен понять где именно разделить.

Comment: `[' - '.join(item) for item in zip(x, y)]` но меня смущает фраза в вопросе "`как получить результат [['y - e'], ['y - e'], ['y - e']]`"

Comment: @Alpensin
Мы можем задать внутри символ,букву,цифру по которой будет производиться разделение.Но да, практики пока мало по этому тяжело так сразу разобраться что не так.

Comment: Убираете просто `.split()` из вашего кода и всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, в данном случае лучше всего использовать не запутанные `join()` и `split()`, а просто обернуть необходимые данные в [f-строки](https://shultais.education/blog/python-f-strings) — так будет и удобней, и понятней :)

```py
x = "tyr"
y = 'red'
result = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    result.append(f'{x[i]} - {y[i]}')
print(result)

# ['t - r', 'y - e', 'r - d']
```

P.S. Ещё Вы забыли поставить `i` как индекс строки, вместо него Вы писали `1`.

UPD: а если говорить о вопросе "почему так происходит?", стоит разобрать данное выражение: `''.join(x[1] + (' - ') + y[1])).split()`. Шаги для его обработки получаются следующие:

1. Сначала выполняется `x[1] + (' - ') + y[1]`. Все литералы строчные, так что скобки в данном случае убираются;
2. В результате данного выражения получится `'x - y'` с пробелами, где x и y — соответствующие символы строк;
3. Функция `join()` ничего не делает, поскольку она работает со списками строк, но здесь строка цельная;
4. Функция `split()` же, наоборот, делит строку на список строк, основываясь на передаваемом ей аргументе. По умолчанию это пробел, так что функция превращает строку из п.2 в список, состоящий из 3 символов-строк.

При снятии пробела же получается строка `'x-y'`, и ни `join()`, ни `split()` ничего с ней не сделают, поэтому сама строка останется прежней.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо:)

Comment: @Maksim добавил ещё ответ на вопрос, почему же поведение программы разное в завивимости от пробелов. И да, если ответ Вам помог, можете отметить его как верный (галочка слева от текста) :)

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = 'tyr'
y = 'red'
z = [' - '.join(item) for item in zip(x, y)]

print(z)
# ['t - r', 'y - e', 'r - d']
```

Но меня смущает фраза в вопросе

> как получить результат `[['y - e'], ['y - e'], ['y - e']]`

```py
[[' - '.join(item)] for item in zip(x, y)]
# [['t - r'], ['y - e'], ['r - d']]
```

---

Но если нужен прямо как в вопросе

```
[[f'{x[1]} - {y[1]}'] for _ in range(len(x))]
# [['y - e'], ['y - e'], ['y - e']]
```